# Woocommerce: reply-to address

Tags: woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in the wordpress.

There are multiple store owners with their own individual products.

When a buyer purchases a product, the owner gets an email notification.

However the email is sent from the admin email and not from the buyer's email.

How can I change the "sender" or "reply-to" so that the owner can reply back to the buyer's email directly instead of the admin email address?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the sender email address in the WooCommerce settings. In WP admin, go to WooCommerce Settings, under the Email tab. There are sub-tabs underneath with all the specific email settings, including setting a from address, although not 100% sure yet on where to configure the reply-to header

Answer (score 1):

You need to run an sql query from your database.
so for change reply-to address run below code:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'new-noreply@email.com' WHERE option_name = 'woocommerce_email_from_address';
```

for replace old address to be sure all things are OK:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'old-noreply@email.com', 'new-noreply@email.com') WHERE option_name = 'woocommerce_email_from_address';
```